# getting ol li :before hover issue

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

I am having ol li for listing. I am using :before and counter(item) because i dont want the period in the list item.
Now i am trying to make it hover effect trying to swap image on hover but its not working properly. Can I get any help how can I make it hover and active class?
What I am doing is not working properly. Please check below my code.

I want the red bg should change to green. Not like the one is working now.

```
.widget-content ol {
  counter-reset: item; 
  margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
  padding-left: 0
 }

.widget-content li {
  display: block; 
  margin-bottom: .5em; 
  margin-left: 2em; 
  color:#999; 
  font-size:12px; 
  font-weight:bold
}

.widget-content li:before {
  background:red; 
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  content: counter(item, decimal) " "; 
  counter-increment: item; 
  display: inline-block; 
  font-size:9px; 
  font-weight: bold;  
  line-height: 18px;  
  margin-left: -29px;  
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;  
  width: 2em
 }

.widget-content li a { 
  color:#999; 
  font-weight:bold
 }

.widget-content li:hover { 
  border:red solid 1px; 
  background: green;
 }

.widget-content li span.commentsCont, 
.widget-content li span.heartCont {
  width:25px; margin-left:0; text-align:right; color:#3b3b3b
 }

.widget-content li span.heartCont { 
  margin-right:5px
 }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fY4kV/)

Comment: Post your html code please and a fiddle.

Comment: We'd need to see a JSFiddle. Your code is **very** hard to read formatted like that.

Comment: You don't have a `:before` AND a `:hover` as a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set hover for `:before` pseudo element as well. check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/fY4kV/2/)**.

```
.widget-content li:hover, .widget-content li:hover:before { 
  border:red solid 1px; 
  background: green;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a selector that expresses both the `:hover` and `:before` pseudoclasses:

```
li:hover:before {
  background: green; 
}
```